# How long does it take for definitely-typed changes to appear in npm @types?

Tags: typescript, npm, definitelytyped, typescript2.0

Lets say I change the typings on definitely-typed for `foo` and the PR is merged into master.

How long will it take for those changes to appear in `@types/foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it needs to be ported across the types2.0 branch. As soon as that is merged it is automatically published

Comment: possibly some delays (I think its still under development and change). But it gets there eventually.